# Android Manifest Error Manifest file doesn't end with a final newline

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:

---

Manifest file doesn't end with a final newline...

Checks whether a manifest file ends with a final newline (as required by JAR specifications)

Expected ":"

---

Here's the AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapplication2.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapplication2.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

It shows on the   android.intent.action.MAIN  line, underlined in red...Android Studio - which it says is the latest version when I click check for updates.

It started to show on a project that had a perfectly working manifest file.  After failed results from researching the error, I made a new project - all defaults - latest version - and did File->Invalidate Caches and Restart (one suggestion I found) but still the same error.

Any ideas, am I missing a setting, etc...
thx

Comment: Sometime i have same issue, in eclipse menu->project->clear all.

Comment: I tried Android Studio's version of this Build->Rebuild Project and also Clean Project but the error persisted.  I appreciate your suggestion though, thx.

Answer (score 7):

Click on the word with the red line (that causes the mentioned error) 
Click Alt+Enter and choose

`Un-inject Language/Reference`

That's it! At least this worked for me on the same error

Comment: This works, but it's pretty opaque and a bit disturbing as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should also have Version code of your app and also SDK versions supported by your app in the manifest file. for e.g., like below

   android:versionName="1.0">

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="11"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.brk.example.test.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
2. Ensure that your package details are correct.
3. Save all the files and do Project Clean.
4. If you still see the error, Restart the Eclipse or again try to reboot the system and restart the Eclipse.

Comment: The Gradle build file contains that info in Android Studio and suggests you put it there if you include it in your manifest.

Comment: Please remember that this is a defaults accepted android studio generated file...that's why I'm thinking I may have inadvertently edited a setting in studio.  I just reinstalled studio and the same error persists :(  I'll take the files back to Eclipse under Mint and see what happens...

Comment: i ported the files back into Eclipse and everything was fine...i must have disturbed a setting in Android Studio...I appreciate all the advice though...thanks for pitching in.

Comment: none of the answers are right.  It's something with Android Studio that I must have 'mucked' up...if that's identified then that answer or suggestion will be corrent.  I can't mark something as the right answer if it's not even about Android Studio - although I am glad you took the time to comment...thx

Answer (score 0):

This one puts out the last byte of each java manifest file, giving a quick visual where there is no newline at the end.

```
find . -name "MANIFEST.MF" -not -path "*target/*" -exec sh -c "ls {}; tail -c 1 {}"  \;
```