# How do I add a final newline in my manifest.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I get an error in my `manifest.xml` which I can't seem to solve.
The error is:

```
Manifest file doesnt end with an final newline.
```

The error occures right before the last `</application>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.matthias.w_seminar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
               </activity>
          <activity android:name=".Difficulty"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
              />
           <activity android:name=".GameNormal"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
              />

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: no issue detected when I copy this code in my Android studio menifest

Comment: I don't find any issue after copied this to my android studio manifest. but try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851090/android-manifest-error-manifest-file-doesnt-end-with-a-final-newline

Comment: Did you edit this file in external editor?

Comment: could you please tell me then how i add a final newline in my manifest in general?

Comment: @MoshErsan no i didnt

Comment: check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26692991/737925

Answer (score 0):

Click on the word with the red line (that causes the mentioned error), then click Alt+Enter and choose

```
Un-inject Language/Reference
```

You can also try to copy your manifest content, delete original manifest file and create new one like this :

[image]

Comment: it seems that this isnt working, all options i get from Alt+Enter are adjust code style settings and Add Newline, which does not work as well .